# Find User Latest single Payment

Tags: sql-server

I am working on an sql server query where i have 2 tables

```
tblUsers(ID,Name)

tblPayments(ID,User_ID,Date,Amount)
```

I want to get the very last payment given by each user. for this i have used the following query-

```
select distinct tblPayments.* from tblPayments inner join tblUsers on  
tblUsers.ID=tblPayments.User_ID
```

but the above query is returning all payments given by the user. But i want only one payment by each user which will be the user last payment. can any one help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
select tblPayments.* from tblPayments 
inner join(select Userid,max(id) as id
 from tblPayments group by Userid) a on a.id=tblPayments.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query to get last payment for each user

```
CREATE TABLE tblUsers (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20))
CREATE TABLE tblPayments(ID INT, User_Id INT, OrderDATE DATE, Payment Decimal)

INSERT INTO tblUsers VALUES (1,'User 1'),(2,'User 2')
INSERT INTO tblPayments VALUES (1,1,'2015-05-02',12.0),
(2,1,'2015-05-03',15.0),
(3,2,'2015-05-06',17.0),
(4,2,'2015-05-07',11.0)


SELECT tp1.*, tu.NAME
FROM tblPayments tp1
 JOIN (
SELECT User_ID,MAX(OrderDate) AS MaxDate
FROM tblPayments
GROUP BY User_Id) tp2
ON tp1.User_Id = tp2.User_Id
AND tp1.OrderDATE = tp2.MaxDate
JOIN tblUsers tu 
ON tu.ID = tp1.User_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

For each User get the latest payment date (used cross apply to achieve it) then used that date to filter those records alone from tblPayments table.

```
   SELECT b.ID,
           b.Date,
           b.Amount
    FROM   tblusers a
           JOIN tblPayments b
             ON a.ID = b.User_ID
           CROSS apply (SELECT Max(Date) AS mx_date
                        FROM   tblPayments c
                        WHERE  a.ID = c.ID) cp
    WHERE  b.Date = cp.mx_Date
```

Comment: Hello, just a small correction on ID field of Payments table: SELECT
 b.User_ID,
 b.ID,
 b.Date,
 b.Amount
FROM tblUsers a
JOIN tblPayments b ON a.ID = b.User_ID
CROSS APPLY (
 SELECT 
  Max(Date) AS mx_Date
 FROM tblPayments c
 WHERE a.ID = c.User_ID
) cp
WHERE  b.Date = cp.mx_Date

Comment: Edited as per @Eralper comments.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Row_Number() function with Partition By clause](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/count-and-row-number-function-for-n-of-m-rows-query.aspx) can help us to order payment records for each user

Here is how the Select query can be constructed with [SQL CTE expression](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=18)

```
with CTE as (
select
    p.User_ID,
    u.Name,
    p.ID,
    p.Date,
    p.Amount,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By User_ID Order By Date desc)
from tblUsers u
inner join tblPayments p on u.ID = p.User_ID
)
select * from CTE where rn = 1
```